# VPN - почему ограничение в одного клиента?

Tags: windows, windows-7, администрирование, vpn

Реализовал FTP-сервер. Работает. Пошёл дальше для удобства пользователей и редактирования файлов в онлайн-режиме создал, местными средствами Windows 7 (64-бит "Максимальная") VPN-соединение. Работает.
Но тут же столкнулся с какой-то неведомой мне причиной - какое-то странное ограничение. Подключается лишь один клиент. Неужели Windows по VPN не разрешает подключение к себе 2-х и более клиентов?
Вспоминаю, как-то было ограничение на подключение по сети внутри локалки (не более 10 клиентов у Windows не серверных версий), но это исправлялось маленькой-прималенькой тулзой.
А здесь как быть? Я не сетевик, поэтому-то и хочу узнать, как это можно разрешить? Т.е. как реализовать подключение, хотя бы до 10 клиентов по VPN на эту машину?

---

Скрин с клиента, который пытается подключиться, даже под другим пользователем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если разрешить подключаться всем одновременно, то кто тогда будет покупать Windows Server? Посмотрите популярный openvpn.

Comment: Будут покупать корпорации типа ГАЗпром, а у меня 3-5 клиентов.

Comment: Кто не покупает, тому и клиентов не положено. А то харя треснет с халявы:), так считает микрософт. Так что сервер на линух, openvpn, хакерские патчи, другие платные vpn-решения, но с менее жёстким ограничением для демо-версий - всё для тебя!